# Java: Getting file name of downloaded attached file (HttpClient, PostMethod)

Tags: java, grails

I'm calling a SOAP service that returns me a file that I save (see code below). I would like to save it using the original file name that the server is sending to me. As you can see, I am just hard coding the name of the file where I save the stream.

```
def payload = """
<SOAP-ENV:Body><mns1:getFile xmlns:mns1="http://connect.com/">
 <userLogicalId>${params.userLogicalId}</userLogicalId>
 <clientLogicalId>${params.clientLogicalId}</clientLogicalId>
```

```
def client = new HttpClient()

def statusCode = client.executeMethod(method)
InputStream handler = method.getResponseBodyAsStream()

//TODO:  The new File(... has filename hard coded).
OutputStream outStr = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\var\\nfile.zip"))

byte[] buf = new byte[1024]
int len
while ((len = handler.read(buf)) > 0) {
    outStr.write(buf, 0, len);
}
handler.close();
outStr.close();
```

So basically, I want to get the file name in the response. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the response headers, set `Content-Disposition` to `"attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\""`

Comment: Thanks for both the answers. Problem was the SOAP service was not adding the filename in the header. When I read the response header I get this <br/> , Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="----=_Part_0_1546767.1329120288435"; start="<ro
ot.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="text/xml"
, Set-Cookie: stage_80_evi=2078807832.1.4098350016.1071872916; path=/

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the API that sends file, you can make sure that the API sets proper [content-disposition header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition). Then in you code where you receive the file, you can read the content disposition header and find the original filename from it.

Here's code borrowed from commons fileupload that reads the filename from content-disposition header.

```
private String getFileName(String pContentDisposition) {
        String fileName = null;
        if (pContentDisposition != null) {
            String cdl = pContentDisposition.toLowerCase();
            if (cdl.startsWith(FORM_DATA) || cdl.startsWith(ATTACHMENT)) {
                ParameterParser parser = new ParameterParser();
                parser.setLowerCaseNames(true);
                // Parameter parser can handle null input
                Map params = parser.parse(pContentDisposition, ';');
                if (params.containsKey("filename")) {
                    fileName = (String) params.get("filename");
                    if (fileName != null) {
                        fileName = fileName.trim();
                    } else {
                        // Even if there is no value, the parameter is present,
                        // so we return an empty file name rather than no file
                        // name.
                        fileName = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

You will need to read the content-disposition header and then split it with ";" first and then split each token with "=" again to get the name value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Content-Disposition Header to determine and save accordingly.

```
int index = dispositionValue.indexOf("filename=");
if (index > 0) {
    filename = dispositionValue.substring(index + 10, dispositionValue.length() - 1);
}
System.out.println("Downloading file: " + filename);
```

Full code is given below using Apache HttpComponents http://hc.apache.org

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
            "http://someurl.com");
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

    try {
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(entity.getContentType());
        System.out.println(response.getFirstHeader("Content-Disposition").getValue());

        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try {
            String filename = "test.tif";
            String dispositionValue = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Disposition").getValue();
            int index = dispositionValue.indexOf("filename=");
            if (index > 0) {
                filename = dispositionValue.substring(index + 10, dispositionValue.length() - 1);
            }
            System.out.println("Downloading file: " + filename);
            input = entity.getContent();
            String saveDir = "c:/temp/";

            output = new FileOutputStream(saveDir + filename);
            for (int length; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            System.out.println("File successfully downloaded!");
        } finally {
            if (output != null)
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {
                }
            if (input != null)
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {
                }
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
    } finally {
        response.close();
        System.out.println(executeTime);
    }
}
```